# get the text after <a/> when parsing HTML DOM using R

Tags: html, r, parsing

I need to get the text after the "a name='race1'/ "  How to use R function to parse it? Will the return value be a list? If so, how to get the value of it? I just need the string"Race 1     1000m     Turf     "C" Course"

```
<td>
 <a name="race1"/>
 Race 1     1000m     Turf     &quot;C&quot; Course
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the XML-package but the string example that you've provided isn't a full html-page and it is therefore hard to parse. I you truly only have that section you can just use gsub:

```
txt <- '<td>
 <a name="race1"/>
 Race 1     1000m     Turf     &quot;C&quot; Course
</td>'

gsub('<td>[^<]+<a[^>]+>([^<]+).*', '\\1', txt)
```

Comment: this is the <div> that contains this <td> tag:

Comment: <div class="rowDiv30">
 <table width="760px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4px" class="color_white font16 bold lineH20">
  <tr class="trBgBlue">
   <td>
    <a name="race1"/>
    Race 1     1000m     Turf     &quot;C&quot; Course
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>

Comment: <table width="760px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
   <td class="trBgBlue">
    <table width="760px" border="0" cellspacing="1px" cellpadding="4px" class="tdAlignC lineH15">
     <tr class="tdBgYellow2 bold">
      <td width="50px">Draw</td>
      <td width="75px">Runners</td>
      <td width="45px">Win</td>
      <td width="45px">2nd</td>
      <td width="45px">3rd</td>

Comment: <td width="45px">4th</td>
      <td width="75px">W%</td>
      <td width="75px">Q%</td>
      <td width="75px">P%</td>
      <td width="75px">F%</td>
      <td width="405px" class="tdAlignL">
How am I supposed to use XML-package to get the the content right after <a/> as mentioned in the  question?

Answer (score 0):

```
library(XML)
txt <- '<td>
  <a name="race1"/>
  Race 1     1000m     Turf     &quot;C&quot; Course
</td>'

xml <- xmlInternalTreeParse(txt, asText = TRUE)
xml['//td[descendant::a[@name="race1"]]/text()'][[1]]
#
# Race 1     1000m     Turf     "C" Course
#
```

So this parses your text into an xml document, then uses the appropriate xPath to index that document. It is a  bit odd that your anchor tag has no text of its own.

Comment: this is exactly what I need!

Comment: Since you're new to SO, please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).